# How to handle multiple form array reactive form method

Tags: angular, forms, reactive

I have array of check boxes. for each check boxes there are multiple field adding option for example under each check boxes i have to add fields 1 and filed 2.
when check box check it should pushed to a form array and also push fields. to that array. How to handle multiple form array in reactive form?

My html is below.

```
<form [formGroup]="progbatchForm" (ngSubmit)="saveProgramBatch()" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-8 m-b-3">
                    <div class="form-group row"  >


                        <div class="col-sm-7"  >
                            <div *ngFor="let programsinterm of programsinterms">
                                        <input 
                                               name="programid" 
                                               type="checkbox" id="{{programsinterm.id}}" 
                                               (change)="ProgramsClick($event.target.getAttribute('id'))"
                                               >
                                        <label class="border-checkbox-label" for="{{programsinterm.id}}">{{programsinterm.programname}}</label>

                                        <div formArrayName="programbatchdetails">
                                            <div >
                                                <table class="table">
                                                    <tr>
                                                        <th>Programbatch name</th>
                                                        <th>Programbatch type</th>
                                                        <td></td>
                                                    </tr>
                                                    <tr >
                                                        <td>
                                                            <input type="text"  
                                                                    class="form-control" 
                                                                    name="programbatchname"
                                                                    formControlName="programbatchname"
                                                                >
                                                        </td>
                                                        <td>
                                                            <select name="programbatchtype"  class="form-control" formControlName="programbatchtype">
                                                                <option value="0">--select--</option>
                                                                <option *ngFor="let progbatchtype of programbacthtypes"  value="{{progbatchtype.id}}" >{{progbatchtype.programbatchtype}}</option>
                                                            </select>
                                                        </td>
                                                        <td></td>
                                                    </tr>
                                                </table>
                                            </div>    
                                        </div>    

                            </div>
                        </div>



                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-6">
                    <button *ngIf="!editstatus" class="btn btn-primary">Save</button>
                </div>
            </div>   
        </form>
```

I need a array structure like this.

```
{
    "programid":"5aeb057175d33208c5333852"
    "programbatchdetails":[
                    {
                   programbatchname:"TEST name",
                   programbatchtype:"Regular",
                   programbatchid:"5aeb057175d33208c5333852"
                },
                {
                   programbatchname:"TEST name",
                   programbatchtype:"Regular",
                   programbatchid:"5aeb057175d33208c5333852"
                }
                 ]  
    },
    {
    "programid":"5aeb057175d33208c5333852"
    "programbatchdetails":[
                {
                    programbatchname:"TEST name",
                    programbatchtype:"Regular",
                    programbatchid:"53sfafafasfasfasfasf"
                },
                {
                    programbatchname:"TEST name",
                    programbatchtype:"Regular",
                    programbatchid:"53sfafafasfasfasfasf"
                }
                 ]  
    }
```

Comment: Add some pieces of your code to get context

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand, you can add a callback to change event and pass it index of your checkbox. Then check if the checkbox is checked/unchecked, as change event will be fired for both kind of changes. Add the checkbox to your FormArray and since you've index of the checkbox passed in, you can loop through fields under that checkbox, check if they're checked and add them to your FormArray as well.

PS -> Post some code to get some code ;-)